# Performance issues mongo on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, python-3.x

We have built a system where videos are stored in mongodb. The videos are each a couple of hundred megabytes in size. The system is built in python3 using mongoengine. The c extensions of pymongo and bson are installed.

The definition of the mongoengine documents is:

```
class VideoStore(Document, GeneralMixin):
    video = EmbeddedDocumentListField(SingleFrame)
    mutdat = DateTimeField()
    _collection = 'VideoStore'

    def gen_video(self):
        for one_frame in self.video:
            yield self._get_single_frame(one_frame)

    def _get_single_frame(self, one_frame):
        if one_frame.frame.tell() != 0:
            one_frame.frame.seek(0)
        return pickle.loads(one_frame.frame.read())


class SingleFrame(EmbeddedDocument):
    frame = FileField()
```

Reading a video in Linux takes about 3 to 4 seconds. However running the same code in Windows takes 13 to 17 seconds.

Does anyone out there have any experience with this problem and any kind of solution?

I have thought of and tested (to no avail):

1. increasing the chunksize
2. reading the video as a single blob without using yield
3. Storing the file as a single blob (so no storing of separate frames)

Comment: is this run as windows service? are you running this code on windows server or workstation? is NUMA enabled?

Comment: Does hardware on both machine is comparatively same? Windows version and disk format type? NTFS?

Comment: I have tested this behaviour both on a laptop (Windows 7 Core i7 with normal harddrive) and on a virtual machine (virtualbox Windows 10) with an SSD. I did not know about NUMA, I will certainly give it a try.

Comment: It is not run as  a windows service, the mongo daemon is started from the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linux, Windows is poorly supported. The use of "infinite" virtual memory among other things causes issues with Windows variants. This thread elaborates further:
[Why Mongodb performance better on Linux than on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178128/why-mongodb-performance-better-on-linux-than-on-windows)

Comment: Unfortunately, the system is required to run on Windows, as most users will have a Windows machine and not a Linux system. If I could choose I would most certainly choose Linux.