# MongoDB Performance : Windows 2016 Server DC vs Same machine running Hyper-V Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, hyper-v

I have read a few articles that say that running MongoDB on Windows is a lot slower than Linux. They mention filesystems like XFS is better than NTFS etc, and that it's more designed for Linux.

Reference [Why Mongodb performance better on Linux than on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178128/why-mongodb-performance-better-on-linux-than-on-windows)

So my question is, has anyone done any benchmarking of MongoDB performance on Windows (e.g installed directly on the server) vs the same machine (running Windows) but it running a VM (Ubuntu 18.04, XFS) via HyperV?

Answer (score 0):

> the same machine (running Windows) but it running a VM (Ubuntu 18.04, XFS) via HyperV

The reason why Linux performs better than Windows for MongoDB is because Linux is more efficient with hardware resources (disk, memory and networking were called out in the post you referenced). Putting Linux in a Windows VM does not eliminate the overhead of Windows that makes it slower for MongoDB. Instead you would have two overheads (Linux AND Windows).

You should also troubleshoot your actual performance problems (per your other post) rather than trying random things like OS changes in the hope that they will make your performance issues go away. The particular issue *might* go away but chances are you'll run into another one down the road, then what?

Comment: This is Hyper-V which I believe sits below Windows so doesn't go via windows